# Adding multiple row entries then dividing sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to get an average

I have the following table:

```
| ClientName | MemberName | TotalAmountSpent | PercentAmountSpent|
|-----Palace--- |---------John---- |-----------376.26------ |------------???------------ |
|-----Palace--- |--------Adem---- |-----------646.83------ |------------???------------ |
|----Pizzeria--- |---------Zoey----- |-----------10.00-------- |------------???------------ |
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  c.ClientName
        ,m.Mem_Name     


        ,Sum(mv.AmountSpent) as TotalAmountSpent
        ,Sum(mv.AmountSpent)/ *100 as PercentAmountSpent


FROM Client c

JOIN MemberVisits mv
On c.ClientId = mv.RestaurantId 
JOIN Member m
On m.Mem_ID = mv.MemberId

GROUP by ClientName, m.Mem_Name

ORDER by ClientName
```

The formula is: `(Total Amount Spent / total business sales) * 100`

for example: johns percentamountspent should be `(376.26/ (376.26 + 646.83)) * 100`

How will I fix this line `Sum(mv.AmountSpent)/ /*Something here */ *100 as PercentAmountSpent` to get the correct output?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible with a single query. The `total business sales` amount won't be available until all rows have been scanned, and you're trying to use that total amount in a per-row calculation. You'll have to use a subquery to get the total first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery (to avoid having multiple SUM in calculation), and an inner join on another subquery to get the totalBusinessSales (which looks like the sum of amountSpent by RestaurantId)

```
select 
    ClientName
    MemName,
    totalAmountSpent,
    sumAmountSpent / totalBusinessSales * 100 as percentAmountSpent
    from

    (select c.ClientName,
            m.Mem_Name,
           sum(mv.AmountSpent) as totalAmountSpent,
           sum(s.TotalBusinessSales) as totalBusinessSales
    from Client c
    join MemberVisits mv on c.ClientId = mv.RestaurantId 
    join Member m on m.Mem_ID = mv.MemberId 
    join (select RestaurantId, sum(amountSpent) as TotalBusinessSales
          from MemberVisits
          group by RestaurantId) s
        on s.RestaurantId = c.ClientId
    group by t.ClientName, m.Mem_Name) i
```

without the first level of subquery, you would have

```
select c.ClientName,
       m.Mem_Name,
       sum(mv.AmountSpent) as totalAmountSpent,
       sum (mv.AmountSpent) / sum(s.TotalBusinessSales) * 100  as percentAmountSpent
from Client c
join MemberVisits mv on c.ClientId = mv.RestaurantId 
join Member m on m.Mem_ID = mv.MemberId 
join (  select RestaurantId, sum(amountSpent) as TotalBusinessSales
        from MemberVisits
        group by RestaurantId) s
            on s.RestaurantId = c.ClientId
group by t.ClientName, m.Mem_Name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am working on your second suggestion, although I get the wrong percent amount spent number...

Comment: @Noonmoon you should the mark the answer as helpful (the check mark) in order to give the poster reputation and to indicate to others what ended up helping you.

Comment: @Kritner Thanks for the tip, I just marked it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf953/4

```
create table test (ClientName varchar(50), MemberName varchar(50), TotalAmountSpent float)
insert into test (ClientName, MemberName, TotalAmountSpent)
select 'Palace', 'John', 376.26
union all select 'Palace', 'Adem', 646.83
union all select 'Pizzeria', 'Zoey', 10

select t.ClientName, 
    t.MemberName, 
    t.TotalAmountSpent, 
    (t.TotalAmountSpent / groupedClientName.totalAmountSpent * 100) as percentAmountSpent
from test t
inner join (
    -- this subquery is used to get the total amount per "Client", which then can be used in the outer query to get a per member contribution percent
    select ClientName, sum(totalAmountSpent) as totalAmountSpent
    from  test
    group by ClientName
  ) groupedClientName on t.ClientName = groupedClientName.ClientName
```